# Specific area in google maps api-Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to use **Google maps api for javascript** in my application. My problem is- I want to use only a **specific area** of a city/region, like a zone or something. I can restrict it to a country (as per the documentation available in Google). But I want only a specific area, that too live one. Google can give you a snap, but its not a real time. Can anyone tell how to do this?

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEKEY&callback=initMap&region=IN">
</script>
```

here region=IN sets the region as India, but how to go to a specific city and locality by default is my question

Comment: Linking to the API and the documentation you have already looked at would be helpful.

Comment: Share your code, and let us know what the issue you face with that particular code

Comment: I have searched the documentation, they only shows setting up the country and language for the default

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's a popular **[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067)** with **121 stars** that matches your requirements in **Google Public Issue Tracker**.

> **Issue Tracker** is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and
>   feature requests during product development. It is available outside
>   of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to
>   collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

By *"starring"* this feature request, it increases the chance to be prioritized by our engineers for their research and development.